# CSS resize image mobile version

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in html/css. I am using a template for my website. Following image bennar.jpg, fits in browser but in mobile view the img is not resized to 100%. Could someone help me to fix it? Very appreciated

```
    .page-header-area {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("images/bennar.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.page-header-area {
  background: url("images/bennar.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

Comment: I had that kind of problem before, and At that time, I tried like the code. You can also do such as "height: 100vw;".

Comment: please pay attention to your edits, this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65715862/image-is-squeezed-in-flex is not using bootstrap at all, it's about talwind and you made the same wrong edit twice now

Answer (score 1):

```
.page-header-area {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("images/bennar.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  min-width:300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! fyi

background-size: 100% auto;